# Set the default selection for a dropdown

Tags: html, jsp, select, dropdownbox

```
<tr>
    <td class="label">
    Filter:
    </td>
    <td>
    <select name="colSearchName" id="colSearchNameID" value="1">
    <%
        colNameIter = content.columnNameIterator( );
        for ( int i = 0; colNameIter.hasNext( ); ++i ) {
    %>
    <option value="<%= i %>"><%= colNameIter.next( ) %></option>
    <%
        }
    %>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input id="autocompleteinput" type=text name="keyword" onKeyUp="autoCompleteOnTable(this.value);">
    </td>
</tr>
```

The above code is a dropdown box in which the values are dynamically selected from the XML file. The `<option>` with a value of `1` should be selected by default but it uses the `<option>` with a value of `0` instead. Setting the `value` of the `<select>` element doesn't help.

Comment: That's not HTML. What is it, asp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you set the selected item. You need to add the `selected` attribute to the `<option>` that you want selected.

For example:

```
<select name="colSearchName" id="colSearchNameID">
<%
    colNameIter = content.columnNameIterator( );
    for ( int i = 0; colNameIter.hasNext( ); ++i ) {
        if (i == 1) {
%>
<option value="<%= i %>" selected><%= colNameIter.next( ) %></option>
<%
        } else {
%>
<option value="<%= i %>"><%= colNameIter.next( ) %></option>
<%
        }
    }
%>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `value` attribute to `Select` won't help because in HTML, the selected option is represented by the presence of the `selected` attribute on the  element like so:

```
<option ... selected="selected">...</option>
```

Therefore, you have to print it conditionally i.e. at every iteration, check for the default value and add `selected="selected"` when condition qualifies. Like in your case, one of possible solutions is:

```
<select name="colSearchName" id="colSearchNameID">
<%
    int defaultValue = 1;
    colNameIter = content.columnNameIterator( );
    for ( int i = 0; colNameIter.hasNext( ); ++i ) {
%>
       <option value="<%= i %>"
       <% if (i == defaultValue) { %> selected="selected" <% } %>
       ><%= colNameIter.next( ) %></option>
<%
    }
%>
</select>
```